# React Js select list to have own value

Tags: reactjs

I have rows of selects lists, when I change a list on one row, the lists for the whole table column change, is there a way each select list can have its own selected option?

I an rendering each row component use the following schema:

```
 tableRowScheme: [
            {"column":"levelId",
                "title":"Level",
                "type": "select",
                "optionData": this.state.gradeOptions,
                "afterChange": this.onLevelSelect,
                "className": "col-md-1"},
            {"column":"subjectId",
                "title":"Subject",
                "type": "select",
                "optionData": this.state.subjects,
                "afterChange": this.onSubjectSelect,
                "className": "col-md-1"},
```

Then Im rendering each select list

```
case 'select': {

            var optionsData = cellData.optionData ? cellData.optionData : [];

            if(cellData.isRowInEditMode && !cellData.isNonEditable) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <TableDropdown columnName={cellData.column}
                                       staticElements={this.props.staticElements}
                                       optionsData={optionsData}
                                       staticElementId={cellData.selectTypeId}

                                       defaultValue={parseInt(this.state.rowDataStack[cellData.column])}
                                       className="input-sm"
                                       handleSelect={this.onDropdownChange}/>
                        <Input type="hidden" ref={cellData.column} standalone={true}
                               defaultValue={parseInt(this.state.rowDataStack[cellData.column])} />
                    </div>
                );
```

Then each dropdown has `this.onDropdownChange` :

```
onDropdownChange: function(data){
    var localRowDataStack = _.cloneDeep(this.state.rowDataStack);
    localRowDataStack[data.filterName] = data.filterVal;

    this.setState({
        rowDataStack: localRowDataStack,
        isOmitReRender: false
    });

    for (var i=0; i<this.props.rowScheme.length;i++) {
        if(this.props.rowScheme[i].afterChange != undefined && this.props.rowScheme[i].column == data.filterName) {
            this.props.rowScheme[i].afterChange(data.filterVal);

            break;
        }
    }

},
```

Comment: can you supply a js fiddle or something?

Comment: Most likely your problem is NOT in the code you provided but somewhere else. My guess: You pass the same `tableRowScheme` to each row (so essentially pointer to the same object). If you then change in one row, you change all rows (because all rows point to the same object).